# When should I reloadData()?

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, swift

I'm switching an existing app to an MVC architecture. I have a Search class which handles data modelling and I have the following function in it:

```
     func performSearch(searchTerm: String){
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(urlForQuery(searchTerm)!, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        let result: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if (err != nil) {
            println(err!.localizedDescription)
        }
        let results: NSMutableArray? = result.objectForKey("results") as? NSMutableArray

            if let testVar = results {
                // Uncomment this to print all feeds
                 println(testVar)
                self.searchedPodcasts.removeAllObjects()
                self.searchedPodcasts.addObjectsFromArray(testVar)
            }

    })
    task.resume()

}
```

This basically queries the iTunes api and returns an Array (searchedPodcasts) of results. When these objects are added to the array, I would like to use reloadData() in my tableView. I understand it would be bad practice to call something like TableViewController.tableView!.reloadData() within this function, but how can I do it once objects have been added to the array?

I have a sort of workaround which I'm not happy with in my TableViewController class:

```
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    println("text did change")
    let length = countElements(searchText)
    if (length <= 3) {
        searchModel.resetSearch()
        searchTableView.reloadData()
    } else if (length > 3) {
    searchModel.performSearch(searchText)
    searchTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This reloads the table view fine, but only when textDidChange is called on the searchBar, which means that once the array has had objects added to it, you need to add/remove a character in the searchBar to call reloadData(). What is a good way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here you should use your reloadData:

```
if let testVar = results {
                // Uncomment this to print all feeds
                 println(testVar)
                self.searchedPodcasts.removeAllObjects()
                self.searchedPodcasts.addObjectsFromArray(testVar)
                searchTableView.reloadData()
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Altimir. This is what I did when I had both my model and controller in the same file, but the function above is not in the VC anymore. Is  it good practice to just call VC.searchTableView.reloadData()?

Comment: For your information, in my model I have tried to create an instance of my VC (let VC = SearchTableViewController()) and call it in the method above (self.VC.searchTableView.reloadData()). Autocomplete works but this crashes the app at runtime.